# msoFileDialogSaveAs not writing file Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Using the following code to copy some data on a master sheet, then add a new workbook, then paste the data. I then need to prompt using the msoFileDialogSaveAs because I need the user to be able to select different file types each time.

The problem is that when the box comes up to save the file, I can type a name then hit save, but it doesn't actually write the file.

```
Public Sub ArchiveSheet()
Dim NewBook As Workbook
Dim CopyRange As Range
Set CopyRange = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Dim lngCount As Long
CopyRange.Cells.Copy
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add
Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    With NewBook
        .Title = "Archive"

    End With

     With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        .Show
     End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Just showing the FileDialog doesn't do anything but give the user the option to indicate where he/she would like to save. So, the file dialog returns the string with the path and the name (where to save and which name). Then it is up to you to use this string or not.

Comment: ok, now I know where to start looking. thanks.

Comment: This might help ; [Open save-as window in file path from cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35434096/open-save-as-window-in-file-path-from-cell/35434946#35434946)

Answer (score 1):

You are currently asking to user to indicate where he/she wants to save the file. But you are not using it. You need to save the return string like so:

```
dim strFileSelected as String
strFileSelected = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls), *.xls", Title:="Save Excel file...")
```

Afterwards you can check if the user actually gave you a path and file name to save it to:

```
If strFileSelected = "False" Then
    MsgBox "You have cancelled"
else
    MsgBox "Saving file here:" & chr(10) & strFileSelected 
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strFileSelected, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookNormal
End If
```

Note that you cannot save all Excel files using any kind of file extension. Example: if you have an open XML format Excel file open and try to save it using the `.xls` extension then you'll probably get an error message and you'll loose any kind of VBA code attached to the file (if you ignore the error message).

In short: you might want to elaborate on the above solution in order to make sure that the file format matches the selected extension using `Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.FileFormat`.

Comment: Just a quibble - I would eliminate the "Not" from your double-negative test and have the success message be the first part of the `If` for two reasons: 1. Double-negatives are confusing (at least to me) 2. It's nice to show the hoped-for result first. I didn't not upvote your answer though :-)

Comment: Hmm. I can't figure it out. I have the variable, how do I turn that into a file?

Comment: Is it this? 
wkb.SaveAs fileSaveName, FileFormat:=xlExcel8

Comment: Tried this, keeps failing after the savefilename = application.filedialog...

 SaveFileName = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs).Show

NewBook.SaveAs Filename:=SaveFileName

Comment: @DougGlancy Thanks for the note, I updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: @purplefolder I updated the above answer to include your second question.

Comment: Just wondering why the file type can't be returned from what the user selects in the drop down? If they do a CSv then it's a CSv, if it's a XLS 97 then do that, why can't the filesave dialog box function just like the main Excel GUI?

Comment: I guess you are mixing up `default` with `Excel will determine the file type for you`. For Excel 2003 (and before) the default is `.xls`. Afterwards the default became `.xlsx` (unless stated otherwise in the options). That does not mean that Excel is determining the format for you. Actually Excel 2007 (and above) asks you which format you want to use by default. Yet, you can even elect to save a standard `.xls` file as `.csv`. But, it is impossible to use the dialog "Save as..." and not get to user to choose an extension (even when the user elects to save without an extension).

Comment: In short: I merely wanted to state that you **might** want to check if the selected "Save as" file format actually suits the file format of the file at hand. But you can certainly skip this part and just save it (by default) to `.xls` or `.xlsx` or - if it is a file which previously existed - in the format it was previously saved as.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I had this issue today, have not seen this answer anywhere...
And the solution was very simply to add the .Execute line, as below.
Now the user hits Save (or Enter) and the selection executes.

```
 With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    .Show
    .Execute 
 End With
```

My first post here, sorry about my obvious lack of skills. I am not an advanced user.
Thanks.